# Firestore push to subcollection with batch.set

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

So what I am trying to acheive here is a data structure like this:

```
id: "BgaI9c5gHB666MpwXPqb"
name: "Rhys Clay"
"pushkey1" : true,
"pushkey2" : true
```

As you can see above I am wanting to store the push keys inside of the document as flat objects.

This is my code so far:

```
let contactsRef: DocumentReference = this.afs.doc(`contacts/${contactId}`).ref;
batch.set(contactsRef, {
  'name'      : contact.name,
  'number'    : contact.number,
  'nativeId'  : contact.nativeId,
  'id'        : contactId,
  groupdId    : true
});

batch.commit();
```

]

But this way I get something like:

```
id: "BgaI9c5gHB666MpwXPqb"
name: "Rhys Clay"
groupdId : true,
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am actually now thinking its better store it as a flat object. Updating my code

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, If saving a variable name as a key, put brackets around it:

```
[groupId]     : 'true'
```